# What is the meaning of this XSLT?

Tags: sharepoint-server, xslt, xslt-list-view-web-part

I want to know the meaning of this following XSLT Code shown below...

```
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="(substring-before(substring-after(@Department,'=*&quot;&gt;'),'&lt;')) = 'IT-Infrastructure' ">
```

Thanks in advance..!!

Answer (score 0):

It trims substrings from left and right side of string:

```
if(Department.TrimLeft("=*&quot;&gt;").TrimRight("&lt;").Equals("IT-Infrastructure"))
{
}
```